# javascript regular expression not working on free web service

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code, i want to develop a web service like rubular.com and i dont know the exact regex command;

I would like the result to be returned as php does it, like a array structure, when viewed with print_r

app also available at : https://github.com/WILL-I-AM/RegEx/blob/master/RegEx.php

this is where it cracks, as it does not return preg_match_all

```
var regex = new RegExp(document.getElementById('regex').value, document.getElementById('regex_params').value);
    var result = regex.exec(document.getElementById('string').value);
```

How do i return the result as preg_match_all does it in php ?

app code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RegEx</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function timeout_trigger() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('regex').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('regex_params').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('string').value;
    var regex = new RegExp(document.getElementById('regex').value, document.getElementById('regex_params').value);
    var result = regex.exec(document.getElementById('string').value);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
function KeyCheck()
{
 if((document.getElementById('regex').value!='')&&(document.getElementById('regex_params').value!='')&&(document.getElementById('string').value!=''))
 {
  setTimeout('timeout_trigger()', 1000);
 }
 else document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "null";
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table
{
background-color:#eeeeee;
}
input
{
height:40px;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
background-color:#000000;
border:1px solid #ffffff;
color:#ffffff;
}
textarea
{
background-color:#000000;
border:1px solid #ffffff;
color:#ffffff;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<table align="center" valign="top" width="1000px" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5pc" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Your regular expression:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="5px"><b>/</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="regex" id="regex" size="135" /></td>
<td width="5px"><b>/</b></td>
<td width="20px"><input type="text" name="regex_params" id="regex_params" size="5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Your text string:</td>
<td colspan="2">Match result:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" valign="top"><textarea name="string" id="string" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></td>
<td colspan="2" valign="top"><div id="result"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to return the result as preg_match_all

Comment: `preg_match_all` is a PHP function. It has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: what is preg_match_all? is that a php function? your question is not even tagged as php, and there's no reason to use php here as javascript can perform the regular expression test.

Comment: nono, i want the equivalent of preg_match_all from php

Comment: `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;` You're trying to stuff a javascript **array** into a dom node as html. Good luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give about the same output as rubular, it allways adds the g option (global) in firefox don't know about other browsers

```
function timeout_trigger() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById('regex').value + ' ' + 
        document.getElementById('regex_params').value + ' ' + 
        document.getElementById('string').value;
    var regex = new RegExp(document.getElementById('regex').value, 
        "g" + document.getElementById('regex_params').value);
    var groups=new Array();
    var matchCounter=1;
    var result=document.getElementById('string').value.replace(regex,
        function(a){
            var foundMatch=false;
            var argcount=1;
            var tmp=new Array();
            while(argcount<arguments.length-2){
                foundMatch=true;
                tmp[tmp.length]=argcount;
                tmp[tmp.length]=":";
                tmp[tmp.length]=arguments[argcount];
                tmp[tmp.length]="<br />";
                argcount++;
            }
            if(foundMatch){
                groups[groups.length]="Match " + matchCounter +":<br />"+
                tmp.join("");
                matchCounter++;
            }
            return "<font style='background-color:#ff0000'>" + a + "</font>";
        });
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result + "<br />" + 
        groups.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Matching a regex in JavaScript will return the first match only, but it will return all the subpatterns.

If you add the `g` flag, then it will return all the matches, but only the entire match text and the subpatterns are lost.

Comment: is there no method that does not loose any data ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. JavaScript's regex functions are designed with the assumption that you know what you are trying to do ahead of time, rather than accepting arbitrary user input.

Comment: if thats the user request, its ok, the code executes on the browser side; i just want to create the same service as rubular does

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for the javascript equivalent of PHP's [`preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, &$matches)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), use [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
matches = subject.match(pattern);
```

where `pattern` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with the *global* flag.

Comment: i fount this : function preg_match_all(regex, haystack, params) {
   var globalRegex = new RegExp(regex, params);
   var globalMatch = haystack.match(globalRegex);
   matchArray = new Array();
   for (var i in globalMatch) {
      nonGlobalRegex = new RegExp(regex);
      nonGlobalMatch = globalMatch[i].match(nonGlobalRegex);
      matchArray.push(nonGlobalMatch[1]);
   }
   return matchArray;
} and it works

Comment: Yes, if you want the `matches` array to contain arrays of backreferences and all, you will need to apply the regex multiple times. Yet, I'd recommend to use [èxec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) for that